# Issues with smtplib, unicode and OpenERP core

Tags: python, odoo, smtplib

I am currently developing a module for OpenERP 6.1.1 (python 2.7) where email notifications shall be triggered by several workflow state changes. So far, so obvious. When I configure an instance of ir.mail_server and want to test it, I get the following exception:

```
Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp61/server/openerp/addons/web/common/http.py", line 592, in send
    result = openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
  File "/opt/openerp61/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 360, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/opt/openerp61/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 572, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/opt/openerp61/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 167, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/opt/openerp61/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 121, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/openerp61/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 176, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/opt/openerp61/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 164, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/opt/openerp61/server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_mail_server.py", line 191, in test_smtp_connection
    smtp_debug=smtp_server.smtp_debug)
  File "/opt/openerp61/server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_mail_server.py", line 241, in connect
    connection.login(user, password)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 598, in login
    (code, resp) = self.docmd(encode_cram_md5(resp, user, password))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 562, in encode_cram_md5
    response = user + " " + hmac.HMAC(password, challenge).hexdigest()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hmac.py", line 72, in __init__
    self.outer.update(key.translate(trans_5C))
TypeError: character mapping must return integer, None or unicode
```

The problem seems obvious, as user and password arguments passed to smtplib.SMTP.login() are unicode encoded, which HMAC doesn't like. If I "fix" the OpenERP core and cast these arguments to string everything seems to work fine. At least the "Test Connection" functionality of ir.mail_server says so.

As I am learning OpenERP as well as Python with this project, I don't know how to proceed though, since there are almost no references to anyone else having this problem. Therefore, my guess is that there is something "wrong" with my development setup triggering this problem. I could just leave the core-patch in there and continue development but this is not really an option, as this might just come back one day and bite my ass.

Any input on this would be great.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, HMAC doesn't like unicode. You can apply the following fix, provided you only use ASCII chars in usernames and passwords. (you have to change line 241 of `/opt/openerp61/server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_mail_server.py` yourself to apply this)

```
connection.login(str(user), str(password))
```

There's a bug in Trac regarding this:

http://bugs.python.org/issue5285